# HingeJoint2D isn't working with Box Collider2D in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools, revolute-joints

I have this character that has an arm as a child gameObject and on that arm there is a HingeJoint2D and a Box Collider2D. The problem is that when I set motor speed, the arm will not move right away, it kinda lags for 1 second or even wont move until I jump with the character, but without the box collider the arm moves right away. I really don't get what the problem is here... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: I don't think the code has anything to do here, but anyway I already solved my problem by using the Auto Mass and setting my collider density to 0. Also I adjusted a bit the motor torque max speed.